# how to use where keyword in roomdb query

Tags: android, kotlin

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val userId: Long,
    val name: String,
    val age: Int
)

@Entity
data class Playlist(
    @PrimaryKey val playlistId: Long,
    val userCreatorId: Long,
    val playlistName: String
)

ata class UserWithPlaylists(
    @Embedded val user: User,
    @Relation(
          parentColumn = "userId",
          entityColumn = "userCreatorId"
    )
    val playlists: List<Playlist>
)

@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM User")
fun getUsersWithPlaylists(): List<UserWithPlaylists>
```

this example many-one from https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships
, my question

if I want to get only users age =10

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM User where age=10")
    fun getUsersWithPlaylists(): List<UserWithPlaylists>
```

but if I want playlistName ="quran"

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM User where playlistName=quran")
        fun getUsersWithPlaylists(): List<UserWithPlaylists>
```

I **cannot** do this because **roomdb does not** see Playlist table

Comment: Maybe `user.playlistName = quran`

Comment: @Andrew not the case

Comment: In your second query you are asking for a user with playlist name. How is that gonna work in any case? If you are a new coder you need to understand basic of querying database. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve. So I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful

```
data class UserWithPlaylists(
        @Embedded val playlists: Playlist,

        @Relation(
                parentColumn = "userCreatorId",
                entityColumn = "userId"
        )       val user: User

)
```

this works fine

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Playlist where playlistName=quran")
        fun getUsersWithPlaylists(): List<UserWithPlaylists>
```

but `roomdb` is so bad with two tables , you cannot do this

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Playlist where playlistName=quran and age=3")
            fun getUsersWithPlaylists(): List<UserWithPlaylists>
```

`where` keyword use only one tables columns.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you need is Called `Join` in SQL databases. I suggest you to learn that using some tutorials. Here is your answer according to your structure.

```
SELECT `user`.`UserId`,`user`.`name`,`user`.`age` From `user` INNER JOIN `playlist` On `playlist`.`userCreatorId`=`user`.`UserId` WHERE `playlist`.`playlistName`='Use your playlist name here'
```

And here is a brief article on `Join`.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: I am not asking about sqlight but roomdb